# Prevent Duplicate Associated Record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I'm working on a simple app where I have this two models:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comments, :user_attributes

  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username

  has_many :reports
end
```

I also have this HAML new report view:

```
= form_for @report do |f|
  .field
    = f.fields_for :user do |u|
      = u.label :username
      = u.text_field :username
  .field
    = f.label :comments
    = f.text_area :comments

  .action
   = f.submit "Submit report"
```

The form sends this JSON parameters:

```
{ user_attributes => { :username => "superuser" }, :comments => "Sample comment 1." }
```

And the simple report controller handles the creation of the record report and user.

```
def create
  @report = Report.new(params[:report])
  @report.save
end
```

This successfully creates a report and a user at the same time. What I need to do is prevent the creation of another *User* if I submit another report with the same username (superuser). Is there an easy way to do this in Rails model or controller? Thank you.

Comment: Can a user submit multiple reports?

Comment: I would be surprised if this currently creates a new user unless there's something else going on. Right now you are instantiating a new Report and saving that, but I don't see it saving a User class. EDIT - is this some Rails magic that I am unaware of?

Comment: @John Yes. username can be used multiple times in sending reports.

Comment: @BrianKung Code for saving a User isn't necessary since it is handled by the association of Rails.

Comment: @BenAluan ah, missed the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the reject_if options to reject the user creation

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, reject_if: Proc.new { |attributes| User.where(username: attributes['username']).first.present? }
```

I would refactor it to:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, reject_if: :user_already_exists?

def user_already_exists?(attributes)
  User.where(username: attributes['username']).first.present?
end
```